# How do i give class attribute to the label of checkbox from the django form

Tags: django, django-forms

In forms.py,

```
aminities = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices= dicto.aminites_dic.items(), 
required=False,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs= 
{'name':'list_details[]','class':'amini'}))
```

In the template,

```
{% for check in form.aminities %}
      {{check}}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: where? what?
you need class in template or in forms?

Comment: Seems like this is not possible; `BoundField.label_tag` is the method that generates the HTML markup; and while it takes `attrs` as an optional argument, Django's `Form` class' `_html_output` does not supply anything while calling `label_tag`.

Comment: @mrash class for the checkbox label in the template

Comment: Got the label using .choice_label in the template .

Answer (score 1):

In general, rather than spelling out the entire field in the template (using a for-loop and explicitely rendering the `choice_label`), you should subclass the widget and replace the template.

```
class SpecialCheckboxSelectMultiple(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    option_template_name = "myapp/widgets/checkbox_option.html"
```

Then in *checkbox_option.html* you customize the code basing it on the original Django code (which you can find in django/forms/widgets/input_option.html):

```
{% if wrap_label %}
    <label{% if widget.attrs.id %} for="{{ widget.attrs.id }}"{% endif %} class="amini">
{% endif %}
{% include "django/forms/widgets/input.html" %}
{% if wrap_label %} {{ widget.label }}</label>{% endif %}
```

Here you can just add your own classes to the label. That way in your template you only need to call `{{ check }}`, and it will use your custom `<label>`